# CakePHP 2.0 How do a print another table column from an id?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

I am new to cakephp 2.x and I am have troubles figuring out how to print a value.

I have the following database relationship.

Table: Customer
   id

Table: FavoriteColor
   id
   customer_id
   color_id

Table: Color
  id
  name

Oh a customer page, I am displaying the customer info with all there relationships.

I am getting the list of customer's favorite color just fine.  But I have the color_id being displayed but i would like to have the color Name displayed in the view.

The view has the following line:

```
echo $favoriteColor['color_id'];
```

I would like to display the color.name field ?  (I am sure this has been asked 100 times.)

Comment: If you are sure it's been asked a hundred times, none of the answers for that hundred times worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
debug($favoriteColor);
```

then, take a screenshot of the results, and post it in your question.

Likely, the solution is to do something like:

```
$favoriteColor['Color']['name']
```

But you'll have to make sure that your associations are set up correctly when you fetch $favoriteColor.